# Can SYSPrep be used to repair user accounts in Windows 10?

Tags: sysprep, windows-10-v1511

There seems to be some problems with my user and system accounts and rights in WIn10, which seem to affect various operations.

I found this article that recommends to use SYSPrep to repair:

https://www.tenforums.com/user-accounts-family-safety/68851-consistency-between-users-users-folders.html

But I read elsewhere that SYSPrep should not be used to make changes to an existing installation, only to create new ones.

Which is correct -- is the repair procedure correct/safe?

Here's the details -- let me know if you need more:

The laptop had been upgraded in place from win7/8 to win10 by a prev owner. There are documented issues with such upgrades, one being messing up the user acct/authority management system: I can create new users but they have no profiles and I cannot login using them. This appears to produce quirks in other functions.

I don't want to apply Windows repair, or resets or anything that will either kill my customization and elimination of bloat that I did. I am running an earlier version of Win10Pro which I cleaned of Cortana and Edge and other apps and if I run SCANNOW for example, they will be returned.

So the question is can I fix this without reinstalling Windows?

Comment: You will be unable to use SysPrep to repair existing user accounts.  If you want help with you user permission problem, we are more then willing to help you, we just need specifics.

Comment: It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 0):

We will need much more information to assist in troubleshooting the user account issue but Sysprep shouldn't be used to "repair" issues with accounts. The article you linked to had the user run Sysprep so he/she could have a "fresh start."

As per [Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721940(v=ws.10).aspx), Sysprep provides the following benefits:

> Removes system-specific data from Windows.
>    Configures Windows to boot to Audit mode.
>    Configures Windows to boot to Windows Welcome.
>    Resets Windows Product Activation

Scenarios in which Sysprep is used:

> Booting to Audit Mode
>   Creating a Built-to-Order Windows Image
>   Creating a Build-to-Plan Windows Image

If you want assistance troubleshooting your issue, feel free to expand on the problem.